# Is the close method on a try-with-resources idiom not called if a constructor throws an exception?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I have a base class `Base` and a child class `Child` which extends it. `Base` implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

Let's suppose that the constructor for `Child` throws a `Foo`.

Now consider

```
try (Base c = new Child()){
    /*Some code*/
} catch (final Foo e){
    /*Some more code*/
}
```

Is the `Base#close` method called if the exception is thrown? It is not on my machine, but is this something that the JLS has standardised?

Comment: If "the constructor for `Child` throws a `Foo`", no instance of `Child` exists in the calling scope, so `close()` cannot be called.

Comment: If there is no object, there is no way `close` can be called on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, `close` won't be called. This is specified in the JLS [section 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> Resources are initialized in left-to-right order. **If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the try-with-resources statement are closed**. If all resources initialize successfully, the try block executes as normal and then all non-null resources of the try-with-resources statement are closed.
>
> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized. **A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value**. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources. Such an exception is suppressed if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource.

In this case, an exception is thrown in the constructor so the resource is not initialized to a non-null value. Hence, the `close` method isn't called.

Answer (score 7):

`close` will not be called. It wouldn't make sense to call it, since you don't have a fully-constructed object to close, and in similar calls, you might not have even entered a constructor:

```
try (Base b = makeBase()) {
    ...
}
```

where `makeBase` is

```
Base makeBase() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: But the base class *is* fully constructed. That's what I'm battling with.

Comment: @P45Imminent: Java doesn't have any concept of base subobjects. There's no fully constructed "Base" object; the object isn't fully constructed until the `Child` constructor completes.

Comment: Thanks for that. Upvoted but can't accept two answers sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to handle it but MAYBE you could delay throwing the exception until AFTER the object is constructed. How? You could have an exception attribute on the class and add a clause to the class's public methods that if that exception attribute is not null, you could then throw the cached exception that originated during object instantiation. This way, you should be able to reclaim the resources that might have been allocated during the partial construction of the object in question. I believe this is how these IO readers and writers classes handle these cases.

Again, this might not be the best way, but it might be something to consider if you REALLY need to.